# Optimize digest loop in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I use Angularjs + Angular material. I create application where I'll able to add tabs dynamically. Each time the user click on the item of an list (item from table) it will show him a new tab with content where the tab-content I'll include a list of template html (I create this list of template inside a component angularjs 1.5). My problem is, when the user open tabX I want that angular digest loop only for the scope on this tab and not $rootScope.digest (in order to optomize my digest loop) because Each tab contain a lot of fields and I will have a problem of performence.

```
<md-tabs md-dynamic-height>
   <md-tab md-on-select="vm.tabChanger(0)">
      home
    </md-tab-label>
</md-tabs md-dynamic-height>
<md-tab-body class="md-marging">
</md-tab-body>

<tbody>
...
<tr ng-repeat="itemTravail in vm.listTravail" ng-click="vm.eltSelectionner(itemTravail)"  class="row-tab" >
...
</tr>

<md-tab ng-repeat="itemTabs in vm.tabs" >
    <content-page>
       <my-Comp1 onj="vm.object"></my-Comp1>
    </content-page>
</md-tab>


(function () {
    'use strict';

    var optionsCaractPropo = {
                        bindings: {
                            onj: '<'
                           //itemSelectionner: '=',
                           // myBinding: '@'
                            //functionBinding: '&'
                        },
                        controller: function($scope,$rootScope){
                                            var vm = this;

                                            console.log('caractPropoController>>>>>>> '+JSON.stringify(vm.onj));

                                            console.log('Outside');
                                            vm.$onInit = function () {
                                                    console.log('Inside');

                                                  }; 
                                              if(!$rootScope.$$phase) {
                                                  $scope.$digest();                              
                                               }

                                              },
                        controllerAs : 'vm',                                              
                        templateUrl: './contentComponents/prepare/views/myComp1.html'       
                 };

    angular.module('prepare')
           .component('myComp1', optionsCaractPropo); 



})();
```

Comment: ideally, the content of all the tabs should be in ng-if i.e. unless the tab is active, it should be taken out of the DOM. That should solve this problem as well

Comment: I've created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/anvp1sw9/) for this but I still get many digest loops and I'm not sure if it's OK. I'm adding it here so you or others can try to improve it. (I couldn't see an improvement with `ng-if` that's why it is commented.)